# Error When attempting to run .exe built with GoLinker from NASM from visual studio: "No symbol file loaded for asmcalc.exe"

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

When I try to debug the file using "Step into new instance", Visual studio returns this in a new tab:

```
Symbol File Not Loaded
No symbol file loaded for asmcalc.exe

Symbol Load Information:
Binary was not built with debug information.
```

This is my assembly code in a file called "asmcalc.asm":

```
global main

section .text

main:
    xor     rax, rax
    ret
```

I use the following commands to build the .obj then .exe:

```
nasm -f win64 asmcalc.asm -o asmcalc.obj
GoLink /console /entry main asmcalc.obj /fo asmcalc.exe
```

Which successfully creates the file, but the aforementioned error occurs when I try to run through visual studio.

Also, after looking at the disassembly, it does not contain the labels I had in the code, which I am not sure if they are supposed to be there or not (I am a beginner with NASM).

NOTE: I am following the tutorial here: https://simon-whitehead.github.io/2018/02/adventures-in-64-bit-windows-assembly-part-1/

Which says that my output should look something like this in the Immediate Window:

```
rsp
(Some hex address)
```

But it's blank for me.

EDIT: The file is not natively built on Visual Studio in MASM, it's built into a .exe that gets imported into Visual Studio then run using the debugger.

EDIT 2: One of the comments mentioned creating a symbol file to fix the issue, how would I do such?

Comment: If doing a native Visual Studio build, using MASM (ML.EXE or ML64.EXE), a debug build will generate a symbol file that the debugger will use. I don't know how to generate the symbol file using nasm and GoLink.

Comment: That shouldn't be an error, just a warning that there's no debugging information so the Visual Studio debugger won't know where `main` or any other symbol is. Microsoft uses a proprietary undocumented format for debugging info so it's unlikely GoLink knows how to generate it.

Comment: @RossRidge If that is the case, how did the tutorial author get that output? Using this same method?

Comment: You need to enter `rsp` into the immediate window. The author seems to be assuming you know how to use the Visual Studio debugger. Having a symbol table won't fix the issue, as RSP isn't a symbol, it's the name of a register.

Comment: @RossRidge For clarification, what issues can arise from the debugger not knowing where main is?

Comment: NASM can generate Codeview 8 debugging information into a win64 object AFAIK. The -g switch enables that.

Comment: In this case not having debug information doesn't matter since your program is so short and `main` happens to be located at the entry point of the program which the debugger always knows. Trying to debug a bigger program without symbols can be a problem because the debugger can't tell you where anything is.  With full debugging information if your program crashes at address 0x401234 the debugger can tell you what line in your source code (if any) corresponds to that address, without debugging info it can only tell you it crashed at address 0x401234.